# Dual-boot Ubuntu and Windows XP on an existing Ubuntu installation

Tags: linux, ubuntu-9.10, multi-boot

I have a computer running Ubuntu 9.10. I want to be able to dual-boot Windows XP and Ubuntu. I have seen other tutorials but they are for older versions and I am afraid of doing something that does not work on newer versions and losing data.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: have you looked through other dual-boot questions on this site?  http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dual-boot

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to tackle this problem. The people over at Ubuntu keep [an article about this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows) very well maintained, as it is one of the most frequently asked questions regarding Ubuntu. It is very easy to follow the guide and determine your version of GRUB. The recommended repair method is via the Ubuntu LiveCD, so if you still got one hanging around, keep it!

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response.

However, this article is for recovery AFTER installing Windows. What I'd like to know is how to go through the process of installing Windows itself, including formatting, partitioning, etc.

Thanks again!

Comment: That's just the thing. If you install Ubuntu first (like you say you did), simply use a partition tool like gparted ( http://gparted.sourceforge.net/ ) to make a reasonably sized NTFS partition for windows, then install windows as usual and boot up into the Ubuntu LiveCD to fix up GRUB.

Comment: Back up first! Any time you repartition or install a new OS you are risking data loss.  The chance is small, but having a recent backup is a good thing anyway.